# Highcharts - Show Year label in x-axis on change

Tags: highcharts

I have a scenario where I only want to include the year in the label when it is changed e.g.

Jan-2011, Feb, Mar,..... Jan-2012, Feb, Mar,....

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Smi the question sounds clear enough to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom [xAxis.labels.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter):

```
     xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 2678400000, //tick every month
        labels:{
            formatter: function() {
                var d = new Date(this.value);
                if (d.getUTCMonth() == 0){
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b-%Y",this.value); // if jan display yeat
                }else{
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b",this.value); // just month
                }                       
            }   
        }
    },
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/83jFz/).

[image]

Comment: what if you don't set tick interval every month and only want the year to appear the 1st time it changes. so say you have 3 dates in jan but the year to appear only on 1st time?

Comment: @bonez, just create a global variable and keep track of whether you've hit that year before.